# I'm trying to detect a language then translate it to English but something is off

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate

> ## I'm trying to detect a language then translate it to English

I've pip installed googletrans then asked a user to input a text that is not in English, created an instance of translator, then after scanning the input it should detect specific language, call the translate and finally print the result

```
from googletrans import Translator

text = input("Enter a text in any language to see it translate in English:\n")

translator = Translator()

lang = translator.detect(text)
print(lang)

translated = translator.translate(text, dest='en')
print("Here is the translated text in English:\n ", translated.text)
```

> ### This is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sardor\Desktop\FALL2020\MOD IV\Python\level\improved_translator.py", line 9, in <module>
    lang = translator.detect(text)
  File "C:\Users\Sardor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 255, in detect
    data = self._translate(text, 'en', 'auto', kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sardor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\Sardor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\Sardor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Can you make any of the example code in the documentation work? Will the code you have work for certain inputs, or not at all?

Comment: Yes, i made some small example code from documentation and it worked. 
the code does not work at all for any input